# Trying to enumerate over a deserialized list throws an exception

Tags: c#-4.0, exception, protobuf-net

I know this exception has been addressed like a billion times but my situation is slightly different (I think).

Anyway, I am using ProtoBuf - Net to save and load objects. I've got a list of objects that I'm trying to deserialize but it keeps breaking saying (here it comes):

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Again, I've seen the question asked like 50 times here so I'm sorry 50 times but here's the code:

```
public void Load(){
            using (var file = 
                File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\TestFile.scn") ? 
                File.OpenRead("TestFile.scn") : 
                null){
                if (file != null){
                    this._tlpGrid.Controls.Clear();
                    this.Scenes = Serializer.Deserialize<List<GraphicsPanel>>(file);
                    foreach(GraphicsPanel gp in this._lgpScenes)
                        this.AddScene(gp);
                }
            }
}
```

Why would it be throwing that exception and what is the proper way to go about this if I'm doing it wrong?

EDIT: It was indicated to me that AddScene method was modifying the list. That is correct:
Original:

```
    public void AddScene(GraphicsPanel Scene){
        this._tlpGrid.Controls.Add(Scene);
        this.Scenes.Add(Scene);
    }
```

Modified:

```
    public void AddScene(GraphicsPanel Scene){
        this._tlpGrid.Controls.Add(Scene);
        if (!this.Scenes.Contains(Scene))
            this.Scenes.Add(Scene);
    }
```

The question has been answered thanks very much.

Comment: what does AddScene() do?

Comment: I assume `AddScene` is modifying `_lgpScenes`, which you can't do while enumerating over it.

Comment: AAAAHGH YOU'RE RIGHT!!! Edited code to reflect.

Comment: If the question has been answered, @lee please write the answer below so it can be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So evidently the issue was that a method I was calling to modify the list was modifying the list while it was iterating through it. It should have been obvious but I completely missed it. Thank you for pointing it out to me, Lee.
The code for the method throwing the exception:

```
public void Load(){
            using (var file = 
                File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\TestFile.scn") ? 
                File.OpenRead("TestFile.scn") : 
                null){
                if (file != null){
                    this._tlpGrid.Controls.Clear();
                    this.Scenes = Serializer.Deserialize<List<GraphicsPanel>>(file);
                    foreach(GraphicsPanel gp in this._lgpScenes)
                        this.AddScene(gp);
                }
            }
}
```

And the method that was causing the issue (Before):

```
public void AddScene(GraphicsPanel Scene){
    this._tlpGrid.Controls.Add(Scene);
    this.Scenes.Add(Scene);
}
```

And after:

```
public void AddScene(GraphicsPanel Scene){
    this._tlpGrid.Controls.Add(Scene);
    if (!this.Scenes.Contains(Scene))
        this.Scenes.Add(Scene);
}
```

Again thanks for patiently pointing out the obvious.